# How to load the db class after the session in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

when i want to make a foreach($_SESSION['banners']->result() as $banner), i get this error:

The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "CI_DB_mysql_result" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in....

how can i load the db class after the session, i am using the native session $_SESSION, i dont want to use the codeigniter sessions because they have problems in IE, how can i resolve this problem?? or what function i need to use to load the DB class after the session in CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the native Codeigniter Session, to avoid such problems. To fix the problem with IE, make the following changes on `config.php`

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_session';
```

to

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'cisession';
```

---

- Initiate the library like this `$this->load->library('session');`
- Set data in the session like this `$this->session->set_userdata('item', 'value');`
- And read the values like `$this->session->userdata('item');`

Then on your application you will able to use it like this

```
foreach($this->session->userdata('banners') ->result() as $banner) {}
```

Comment: OP specifically said "i dont want to use the codeigniter sessions because they have problems in IE"

Comment: thanks, but i am wondering if i can put somewhere the session_start() that will be executed before the DB classes are loaded, can be taht place?

Comment: @yeahitsme, the problem is not that, the session variable will have reference to the db class which will not have been loaded, when its used. You should just stick to the method that works, and save time inventing another way. But may be creating hooks will be able to help you.